# where can i remove the resultnumber for search?

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, search

[image]when adding a search term,sometimes ther eis a dropdown with results sowing also a number before it (the number of expected results?)

Is that a setting somewhere or would i need to do something in code?

thanks

Comment: can you provide a screenshot for your issue.

Comment: i added a printscreen

Comment: Looks like a customized search autocomplete where the result is placed in front of the search term. You should check your template for adaptions to this.

Answer (score 2):

To explain what happens during your search auto-suggest, I add some information about the search-functionality related to this here:

Searching for 'trousers' (actually 'trou') in the demo shop:
GET http://demo.magentocommerce.com/catalogsearch/ajax/suggest/?q=trou gives you the following return via AJAX:

```
<div id="search_autocomplete" class="search-autocomplete" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 40px; width: 300px; display: none;">
  <ul>
    <li class="selected" style="display:none"></li>
    <li class="odd first" title="trousers">
       <span class="amount">1</span>
       trousers
    </li>
    <li class="even last" title="trouser">
       <span class="amount">4</span>
       trouser
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

From the request above you can see that the suggestAction from the CatalogSearch AjaxController.php is called. The suggestAction calls `$this->getResponse()->setBody($this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalogsearch/autocomplete')->toHtml());` to return the search-output.
Opening `app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Block/Autocomplete.php` you  will see that the HTML-code for your autosuggest-text is created there which is shown above.

In the `_toHtml()` function there is an inline-element named `<span class="amount">` which shows the number of results for the term. You might have a CSS-rule for `.amount` or one of the other CSS-classes around `.search-autocomplete` which were modified.
Or there might have been someone/something rewriting the `app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Block/Autocomplete.php` block class.

Answer (score 0):

In Magento Admin > System > configuration > Catalog > Catalog Search > Show Autocomplete Results Count

Set this field to "No" from drop down and the count will not be visible on front end.